# Remove Duplicates from MYsql table using MinID and Complex Select

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I found this here to delete records with min ID:

```
DELETE FROM Table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM Table GROUP BY FieldA)
```

However I don't want all the found dupes in the table to have the one with the lower ID removed, only a subset of them. I have other criteria for other dupes patterns. So I made my select to get the subset of records that have dupes AND other conditions where I then DO want the min ids removed:

```
Select min(Z),Max(Z),count(*) from Table  
group by P,N
having count(*)>1 and Min(Z)!=Max(Z) and Min(Z)>0
```

I am unclear how to first get that subset of records and THEN remove the minID from the dupes in that subset

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
delete t
    from table t left join
         (Select min(Z), Max(Z), count(*) 
          from Table  
          group by P, N
          having count(*) > 1 and Min(Z) <> Max(Z) and Min(Z) > 0
         ) tt
         on t.? = tt.?
    where tt.? is null;
```

It is unclear how the `id` is defined in your expression.  It is also unclear whether the subquery generates the ids to keep or to delete.  The version above assumes it is generating the ids to keep.  (If it generates the ids to delete, then use `inner join` and get rid of the `where` clause.)

Comment: My expression is simply to generate a subset of the table where a) there are duplicates that b) I want to remove the ones with the lowest ID. There are duplicates in the table that exist where I do NOT want to remove the min(id) version of the duplicate otherwise I'd simple run the original delete min id. So what should be happening in effect should say 'find the subset of records in tableA that are duplicates AND meet this additional criteria and THEN remove the one with the lowest ID'

Comment: @user3649739 . . . This can all be handled with `join`s.  However, your explanation still is not 100% clear.  Sample data and desired results -- particularly including edge cases -- are useful.